# How can I let Edge ask for being the default browser?

Tags: macos, microsoft

On my Mac I use Safari for private purposes and Edge for work purposes.

When I'm working, it's convenient to have Edge as the default browser. Now I have to set it each day manually (after the working day I set it back to Safari, which asks for that).

What I want is that Edge does ask for being the default browser. Is this possible?

NB: Using a different account is not convenient for the way I work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [brew](https://brew.sh/) installed, you can use the [defbro](https://github.com/jwbargsten/defbro) *(default browser)* utility.

###### Installation

Launch a terminal (e.g. Terminal.app) and run the following command:

```sh
brew install jwbargsten/misc/defbro
```

###### Set Safari as the default browser

```sh
defbro com.apple.Safari
```

###### Set Edge as the default browser

```sh
defbro com.microsoft.edgemac
```

###### Keyboard shortcuts

If you want to do the above actions faster, you can use the free [iCanHazShortcut](https://github.com/deseven/iCanHazShortcut) app to assign keyboard shortcuts to the commands.

Install the app using `brew install icanhazshortcut`, launch it, click on the ⊕(plus) button in the bottom right of the window and configure it as in the following screenshots:

[image: screenshot showing how to configure a keyboard shortcut for setting default browser to Edge]
[image: screenshot with all keyboard shortcuts configured]

Comment: I'm trying to execute the command via Automater but getting the error "zsh:1: command not found: defbro". Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Automator might not inherit the shell path. You could use the full path for defbro: `/usr/local/bin/defbro`

Answer (score 2):

I would have two accounts; one for work with Edge set as default and one for private.

I also have an Admin account to make sure I don't change important things by accident, as well as accounts for each kid...

And I make accounts for family visiting as well. No interfering with my data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Opening via Terminal might help.

```
open -a "Microsoft Edge" --args --make-default-browser
```